# How to add HTTP header to NSURLMutableRequest with non english letters (ø , æ, etc..). and get it to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-headers, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to get some data from a backend endpoint where a custom authorization header is required.
it works normally whenever the username contains English Characters only. If the username contains any non english characters the server returns 401 unauthorized.

I set the header as follows:

[urlRequest setValue:@"Authorization" forHTTPHeaderField:@"MyProject-ApiKey **søren**:drt38f0s9a21"]; //if the name is mike instead of søren it works normally. noël won't work.

I tried to manually hardcode the ø character unicode code point (\U00F8) in the header value but it didn't work as well. What should I do to the value before setting it as a header to make it work? I was able to consume this endpoint in android with non English letters. So the problem isn't on the server side.

Note: I get the below log right before the request fails

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = htps;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sdmn = "django-tastypie";
    srvr = "domain.com";
    sync = syna;
}
```

Below is how I request it

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://domain/endpoint/?queryParam=3"];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[urlRequest setValue:[self getHeaderValue] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    if(httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
    {
      //comes here with english letters
    }
    else if(httpResponse.statusCode == 401)
    {
        //comes here with non english letters
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

Update: I tried it on postman and it fails to work as well. Only works with English letters.

Comment: Headers might need to be in UTF8, what about percent escape them maybe? Check the server specs?

Comment: @Larme Tried both UTF8 and percent escape. didn't work. What I was trying to know before getting back to the server side developers is why it works on android but doesn't work on ios or postman.

Comment: Might want to check what's doing Android. Is it escaping it by default?

Comment: I used fiddler to intercept the request it just shows the character no escaping or encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. I ended up asking for a server side change which is expecting the username in the header to be base64 encoded.